# Message error with tkz-fct

Tags: errors, tkz-fct

I have a problem with the `tkz-fct` package. I now have this error message when compiling:

```
! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \tkz@tmp@xa
l.15 \tkzFct{\x}
?
```

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
\tkzInit[xmin=-1,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=5]
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[domain=0:4]{\x}
\tkzFct[domain=0:4]{\x-1}
\tkzDrawAreafg[color=green,domain = 1:3]
\tkzRep
\tkzText(5.2,3.5){$\displaystyle{\int_{1}^3 f(x)-g(x)dx}$}
\draw [->] (4.1,3.5) -- (2.6,3);
\tkzText(2.5,4.2){$\mathscr{C}_f$}
\tkzText(2.5,1.2){$\mathscr{C}_g$}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

I am using the last version of TikZ and of `tkz-fct`. The PDF file is compiling but I have this (these) error(s) anyway.

Can someone tell me where it comes from?

Tried with the suggested mods but I have the same message. The problem seems to come from the tkz-fct package. I use the last version of tkz-fct.sty

Comment: I reformatted your error message using 4 space indent as I _hope_ it was from TeX. You had it on one line but that loses vital information: the last token before the linebreak is the command that is undefined and so generating the error.

Comment: I can't get that error message; I even tried with TeX Live 2011, 2012 and 2013 (not earlier versions, because TL 2010 hasn't `tkz-fct`).

Comment: Thank you, I had troubles understanding the 4 space indent thing ... Not good enough in English I fear :-(

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the package `mathrsfs` for this. When compiling your code, I got some other message than you. Please check again. The problem for me was that `\mathscr` was not defined.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-1,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=5]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzFct[domain=0:4]{\x}
    \tkzFct[domain=0:4]{\x-1}
    \tkzDrawAreafg[color=green,domain = 1:3]
    \tkzRep
    \tkzText(5.2,3.5){$\displaystyle{\int_{1}^3 f(x)-g(x)dx}$}
    \draw [->] (4.1,3.5) -- (2.6,3);
    \tkzText(2.5,4.2){$\mathscr{C}_f$}
    \tkzText(2.5,1.2){$\mathscr{C}_g$}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add

```
usepackage{stix}
```

otherwise `\mathscr` isn't defined, which should be the correct error message.

Comment: Why `stix` that also changes all the math fonts?